# Why my program have a infinite loop?

Tags: assembly, dos, dosbox

I made a simple program using assembly language, for implementation I'm using `MS-DOS (DOSBox)` here the code :

```
.model small
.code
org 100h

mulai:

mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 'Z'
mov cx, 10h

lagi:

int 21h
inc dl
inc cx

loop lagi
int 20h

end mulai
```

I tried `loop` implementation but gain `infinite loop`, so what wrong with my code ?

Comment: And since you are using `org 100h` are you trying to make a COM program (and not an EXE). If so you'll want to use `.model tiny` ?

Comment: If you are trying to loop 16 times (10h) then you'll simply need to remove the `dec cx` as the loop instruction decrements `cx` on each interation automatically

Comment: Why don't you ask your debugger first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`loop` decrements `cx`, and jumps to the address given if `cx` is not 0.

Since you increment `cx` on each loop iteration, `cx` will never become 0 and you have an infinite loop.